# Starting mysql in xampp

Tags: xampp

I have recently reinstalled xampp and I'm getting this message

```
    23:56:45  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
    23:56:48  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
    23:56:52  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
    23:56:52  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    23:56:52  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    23:56:52  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    23:56:52  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    23:56:52  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    23:56:52  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
    23:56:52  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

I have removed and reinstalled it.
Any further advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another application may block the database port 3306 or maybe the folder for temporary files is missing or not writable. The latest version of xampp has a tool in the control center that lists the used ports. 
If you are using windows you should move the xammp folder to a location where there is no problem with writing files, try your documents folder for example.